# how to get option group of selected item on .chosen().change()

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

For a simple option grouping, say:

```
   <optgroup label="fruit">
     <option value="1"> apples </option>
     <option value="2"> pears </option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="veg">
     <option value="3"> neeps </option>
     <option value="4"> tatties </option>
  </optgroup>
```

I'm able to get grab the selected option's id...  Using:

```
    $('#my-chzn').chosen().change(
        function(evt) {
           var id = $(this).val();
           // ...or 
           var id_ = $(evt.target).val();
        }
    );
```

But is it possible to grab the `<optgroup>` label for a selected option? 
ie is there a handle/selector to grab the value 'fruit' when the selected option is 'pears'?

Many thanks for any help anyone's able to offer....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want as the code is shown below

```
$('.chosen').chosen().change(
    function (evt) {
      var label = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).closest('optgroup').prop('label');
      alert(label);
});
```

[Demo on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/nYT7x/)

Comment: `$(this.selectedOptions).closest('optgroup').prop('label')` is a little bit shorter